# TPL Failed to start a process

Tags: c#, process, cmd, task-parallel-library

What went wrong with the following code? I like to start a process and update UI when the comprssion is done.

The error is The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

```
    string sArgs = "a all.zip a.txt b.txt c.txt";
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("7z.exe", sArgs);
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
    psi.LoadUserProfile = false;
    Process proc = new Process();

    Task t1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            proc = Process.Start(psi);
        }
    );

    button13.Enabled = false;
    Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
        {
            button13.Enabled = true;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );

    t1.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Are you running on windows?
- Is `7z.exe` in the system `PATH` ?
- Is the `7z.exe` file 64-bit whereas your OS is 32-bit ?

Comment: what difference would 32 vs 64 bit make here?

Comment: @Bond, you can't run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I guess the 7Zip would be the right version if it has been installed already.

Comment: Yes. I am running on Windows and 7z.exe is in the system PATH. Oops! that 7z.exe is a 64-bit one and my OS is 32 bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: This code will enable button13 immediately because your main task does not wait for the process to exit. This code should do the trick:

```
string sArgs = "a all.zip a.txt b.txt c.txt";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("7z.exe", sArgs);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.LoadUserProfile = false;
Process proc = new Process();

Task t1 = new Task(() =>
    {
        proc = Process.Start(psi);
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
);

button13.Enabled = false;
Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        button13.Enabled = true;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);

t1.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 7z in your path? you can set it via the [EnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) property of your psi